# Python: Value Error: Watchdog Numpy.Load()

Tags: python, numpy, load, watchdog

Situation:

Live Camera captures numpy arrays and saves with utc timestamp and exposure time (ms) in a folder.

A parallel running script watches the folder, where the images are saved as .npy files:

```
import numpy as np
from watchdog.observers import Observer #https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

os.chdir("/home/pi/testenv/processing") #dir where camera saves images as .npy

class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    # after one images arrive: functions activates
    def on_created(self, event):

        img_id = os.path.basename(event.src_path)       
        print(f"img_id: {img_id}")

        temp = np.load(f"{img_id}", allow_pickle=True)  
        print(f"temp.shape {temp.shape}")


while True:

    path = "/home/pi/testenv/processing"  
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, ".", recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

I get the following error message, it varies in timing (sometimes after 3 frames, sometimes after 10 frames):

```
img_id: 1669897126_60.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669897126_106.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669897126_166.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669897126_273.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669897126_470.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669897126_773.npy
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 205, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 381, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/watchdog/events.py", line 272, in dispatch
    {
  File "/home/pi/testenv/watch_npy.py", line 52, in on_created
    temp = np.load(f"{img_id}", allow_pickle=True)  # type(temp) = narray
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 413, in load
    return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 785, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1520,2032)
```

**I suspect** since the images are captured and saved live that **the file isnt yet fully saved while it is already loading..**

If I check the image where the error message occurs, the shape is always correct (1520,2032).

How can I make sure the numpy array is completely saved before I load it... Or what else is triggering that problem?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    # after one images arrive: functions runs once
    def on_created(self, event):

        img_id = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
        img_utc = os.path.basename(event.src_path).split('_')[0]
        img_utc_exp = os.path.basename(event.src_path).split('.')[0]
        img_exp = img_utc_exp.split('_')[1]

        print(f"img_id: {img_id}")
        try:

            temp = np.load(f"{img_id}", allow_pickle=True)  # type(temp) = narray
            print(f"temp.shape {temp.shape}")

        except:
            print("file did not load completely - trying again#1")
            try:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                temp = np.load(f"{img_id}", allow_pickle=True)  # type(temp) = narray
                print(f"temp.shape {temp.shape}")
            except:
                print("file did not load completely - trying again#2")
                try:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    temp = np.load(f"{img_id}", allow_pickle=True)  # type(temp) = narray
                    print(f"temp.shape {temp.shape}")
                except:
                    print("fail")
        else:
            print("success")    



img_id: 1669900308_60.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_106.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_166.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_273.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_470.npy
file did not load completely - trying again#1
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
img_id: 1669900308_773.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_1258.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_2032.npy
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
success
img_id: 1669900308_3291.npy
file did not load completely - trying again#1
temp.shape (1520, 2032)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code provided, I think as you said, file is read before being saved. try below steps:

1. Check the ndarray shape to be (1520,2032), else catch the exception, where you wait and call the method again, else avoid the file completely.
2. Else maintain a *.db/.txt/.pickle* of the files being saved, with their timestamps and status of whether read/unread. This way even if you catch an error, you can re-read it again. ***(Try aiofile, asyncio.sleep(x) for better performance.)***

Comment: Thanks for participating. the 2. idea seems to be the way iam looking for: a kind of check, that the file is "completely" saved before read..